# How to show that $f$ can only have at most one root in $(a,b)$ with these conditions?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

Let $f: [a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function on $(a,b)$.

Suppose $f$ has the following property:

If for an $x \in (a,b)$, $f(x)=0$, then $f'(x)>0$.

The excercise is to show, that $f$ can only have at most 1 root in $(a,b)$.

Comment: HINT: Try to draw f. What would a root of f look like?

Comment: What difficulty are you having with this exercise?

Comment: You can have a look at theorem 5.11 in Principles of Mathematical analysis, 3rd 3d.